# How to get lookup value only via REST (listdata.svc)

Tags: lookup-column, listdata.svc, rest

I am trying to retrieve a list of items including lookup fields via `listdata.svc`. My lookup points to a list of companies which has the following fields: **Title, Address, Phone**.

By default, listdata doesn't return the lookup data, only a link to it. If I use the `$expand` parameter, then listdata returns all the fields of the lookup.

How can I make listdata return the lookup **Title** only, not the other fields like **Address** and **Phone**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This page has some good examples on using listdata.svc and specific examples on drilling down into specific items to be selected.

[Using the REST Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)

Examples from page

Using code:

```
var query = (DataServiceQuery<InventoryLocationsItem>)context.
    CreateQuery<InventoryLocationsItem>("InventoryLocations")
       .Expand("Part")
       .AddQueryOption("$select", 
                       "BinNumber,Quantity,Title,Id,PartId,Part/SKU,Part/Title")
       .Where(p => p.Part.SKU.StartsWith(SearchSku)).OrderBy(p => p.Part.SKU);
```

Manually constructing the URL:

```
http://contoso/sites/sharepointlist/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/InventoryLocations()
  ?$filter=startswith(Part/SKU,'sku')
    &$orderby=Part/SKU
      &$expand=Part
        &$select=BinNumber,Quantity,Title,Id,PartId,Part/SKU,Part/Title
```

Comment: thx, I'll try this. The [list]/[column] notation seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Worked great! Do you happen to know how to get rid of the _metadata?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I do not know how to get rid of the _metadata.

Comment: It shows 'An error occurred while processing this request' if the lookup value is null. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Title is the "foreign key" don't you already have that value in the primary list? Alternatively, don't you get the values if you add the other columns to the Lookup column to pull them across with the key?

Comment: No you don't (contrary to what Web services will do for example). You don't get the lookup id either. Let's say that REST services are very "performance concious" ;-)